# Offline documentation of an RPM spec file or how to retrieve an example

Tags: rhel, rpm, documentation

I am taking a Red Hat exam that is offline. I am having issues remembering the syntax for an RPM SPEC file.

Can anyone suggest how to retrieve an example or some documentation that should already be in the system? Cannot seem to find anything like that.

(This is not cheating. We are allowed to use anything on the system.)

Comment: Yes, but you should already know how to find any documentation on the system.

Comment: @Shawn, I do but does not hurt to ask for tips. There has been a few times where I found nice examples by chance. Please, give your suggestion below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `emacs foo.spec` that will create a spec file with the basic layout. That is part of the emacs-common package which will hopefully be installed. If you don't know emacs, just run that command, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save it then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit then you can open the spec in your favorite editor.

CentOS 5 has /usr/share/doc/rpm-4.4.2.3/spec which contains some basic info. It comes with the rpm rpm which should be installed on any server. CentOS 6 will have something installed in a similar location.

If you poke around /usr/lib/rpm there might be useful stuff in there.